# Facing net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED in Ionic 3

Tags: typescript, ionic3

After updating ionic and cli. I suddenly started facing net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED whenever calling a Rest API on actual android device.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by

adding

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
</edit-config>
```

to config.xml.

Then add

```
<access origin="*" /> <allow-navigation href="*" />
```

to /resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <network-security-config>
   <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
     <domain includeSubdomains="true">yourdomain.com</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

to config.xml in the widget inside the `<platform>` for android.

Then

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
```

and

```
ionic cordova platform add android@7.0.0
```